# IOS Self Sizing UITableViewCell with auto layout don't work for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to implement auto resizing UITableViewCell by auto layout. I have Table View Prototype cell (Custom Cell).

I have one UIImageView which has TopSpace, BottomSpace, LeadingSpace to view, Height & Width as constraints.

I have UILabel Which has Top, Horizontal space to UIIMage View Trailing Space to view and vertical space to UILabel at bottom.

I have another UILabel which has Horizontal Space to UIImage View Trailing space to view and bottom space.

I have set Lines to 0. for both label and added

`self.tblview.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0f;
 self.tblview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Also i have following code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

`[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
 [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
 [cell setNeedsLayout];`

This is not working for first time but when i scroll down and scroll up auto sizing works like a charm.

Can any one please help me here ?

Comment: The fix is probably remove the first two lines in your post, and uncheck `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for the label in storyboard.

Comment: Than there would be no auto re sizing in uitableviewcell

Comment: Sharing your project would be great, because it is not reproducible for me.

Comment: are the steps perfect for making uitableviewcell autoresizable ? If you have any new way please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

after

```
[cell setNeedsLayout];
```

It may works.